# Motorola ES400 Internet Explorer (IE6) zoom issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-phone, motorola

I developed the website that compatible with IE6 and IE Mobile 6, But I am getting the problems related to the zooming and viewport in the IE6 and IE mobile 6. My some pages of the website display in perfect zoom but some page display in `zoom out`.

When my page content is less than it display okay, but when page content is large and exceeds the motoroal ES400 screen mobile than it display the `Zoom out` my whole page display in small screen, I want to prevent that I want to display that same as small content page is display.

I want to use my web site in the `IE6` and in the `IE Mobile 6`

I added some `meta tag` related to the `viewport` but it does not make any difference.

I used the below meta tage:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8; width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

and

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

and

```
<meta name=“mobileoptimized” content=“480”>
```

I used all above meta one by one but it does not do any impact on the `IE6` and `IE Mobile 6`

But If I used the above meta tag and view my website in chrome or firfox than it works good.

Also when I open my website in the IE6 and try to zoom in and zoom out forcefully it also does not work, My website can not be zoom in or zoom out in the IE6, but it zoom in and zoom out in the chrome.

Comment: IE6 did not know about X-UA-Compatible or name=viewport. Hope this answers your question. Also, your first meta statement is wrong; maybe a copy and paste error?

Comment: Thanks for reply @MrLister, Yep seems like it. Is there any other way to workaround this zoom out problem on particular pages?